# Find the volume of a solid bounded by $x^2+y^2 + z = 4$ and $z=0$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need help finding (and understanding) the volume of a solid bounded by $x^2+y^2 + z = 4$ and $z=0$.

Comment: (please excuse my english)I have converted to cylindric, and integrate : theta between 0 and 2pi , r between 0 and 2 .. and z between 0 and 4 - r^2

Comment: I'm getting 8pi as result

Comment: @MarianoB Show us what you tried by editing your question and writing it on $LaTeX$.

Comment: @MarianoB I do get the same as you: $\;8\pi\;$ .

Comment: Thank your for posting. Rebellos, I don't know how to use LaTeX, I'm going to find about It, thank you. DonAntonio Thank you for validating my resultt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boundary on the $xy$ plane is a circle of radius $2$, so we can integrate in cylindrical coordinates

$$ \iint (4-x^2-y^2)\ dy\ dx = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2 (4-r^2)\ r\ dr\ d\theta = 2\pi \left(4r - \frac{r^4}{4} \right)\Bigg|_0^2 = 8\pi $$